# how to connect points after identifying them in cvgoodfeaturesTotrack

Tags: opencv, video-processing

I want to identify an object and draw a shape around it ...

I used previously the color identification but wasn't a good option since color change dramatically from place to place .. so I though why not identifying objects by features such as edges .. and I did that using this function in openCV

cvgoodfeaturesTotrack

it returns the (x,y)-coordinates of the points .. now I want to connect those points.. well not all of them but the one who are close to each other to draw a shape around the different objects. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a free lunch in this case. You are trying to reconstruct a polygon if you only know the corner points of the polygon. There is no unique solution to this problem: you can draw all sorts of polygons through the corners. If you are certain the shape you are after is convex, then you can construct the convex span of the corner points, but the result will be horrible if you include any corners that were not part of the original object.

It seems to me that detecting corners is not the way to segment an object that is more or less delimited by lines. You probably want to try an edge detector instead, or a proper segmentation technique such as watershed.